# RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: [object Object] error express 4.16

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-4

I'm implementing a password reset and when clicking on the generated link I'm getting the following error,

```
Thu Jan 25 2018 16:54:38 GMT+0000 (GMT): GET /users/reset/d590c54753abc449cfcd8aefceb8d519fce4b627
express deprecated res.redirect(url, status): Use res.redirect(status, url) instead routes/users.js:297:9
events.js:136
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: [object Object]
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:193:11)
    at ServerResponse.writeHead (/Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:55:19)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:184:8)
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:644:9)
    at ServerResponse.write (_http_outgoing.js:629:10)
    at writetop (/Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/express-session/index.js:290:26)
    at ServerResponse.end (/Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/express-session/index.js:338:16)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (/Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:947:10)
    at /Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/routes/users.js:297:9
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (/Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4056:16)
    at /Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
    at /Users/benbagley/Code/poetry-out-loud/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here are my routes

```
// Token URL :get
router.get('/users/reset/:token', (req, res) => {
  User.findOne({
    resetPasswordToken: req.params.token,
    resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() }
  }, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
      res.redirect('/users/forgot');
    }

    res.redirect('reset.hbs', {
      pageTitle: 'Reset Your Password',
      user: req.user
    });
  });
});

// Token URL :post
router.post('/users/reset/:token', (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.body.password === req.body['password-confirm']) {
    next();
    return;
  }

  req.flash('error', 'Passwords do not match!');
  res.redirect('back');

  User.findOne({
    resetPasswordToken: req.params.token,
    resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() }
  }, function(err, user) {
    if(!user) {
      req.flash('error', ' Password reset is invalid or has expired');
      res.redirect('/login');
    }

    const setPassword = promisify(user.setPassword, user);
    setPassword(req.body.password);
    user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
    user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;
    const updatedUser = user.save();
    req.login(updatedUser);
    req.flash('success_msg', 'Your password has been reset successfully! You are now logged in!');
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
  });
});
```

I think, I'm close to getting this to work, just a few errors I'm running into. This being one of them. I have checked the documentation and I'm not seeing anything mentioning status codes, I believe this is a change in the recent framework, seems quite odd having to define a status code for every redirect or render.

Comment: If you have another question, please ask another question.  It's poor form to edit your existing question with another question, as that runs the risk of invalidating prior answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use [res.render](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render) instead of [res.redirect](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect):

```
res.render('reset.hbs', {
  pageTitle: 'Reset Your Password',
  user: req.user
});
```

[res.redirect](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.redirect) method accept the route string as arguement while [res.render](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render) accept a string that represent the file path of the view to render

Comment: @B.J.B I think you should create another question because it's not related to the first post, that's why your edit was removed, however create another question and all the members of SO community are here to help